# How to get the interface type from Win32_CDROMDrive WMI class?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I have achieved that target for [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but in [Win32_CDROMDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class there no exist that property (**InterfaceType**).

How can get the interface type for a optical drive? Exists another mean to obtain it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you run `Win32_DiskDrive` against the CD-ROM interface?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, it only shows the actual hard disk drives installed on the computer.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can get it from that class.  If you check the first 3 characters of the PNPDeviceID, you can tell if it's USB, but that's about it.  See http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/disk/drives/

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the interface type from the `DeviceID` or `PNPDeviceID` properties.

Try this sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementScope Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", "localhost"), null);
                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_CDROMDrive");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    String InterfaceType =  ((String)WmiObject["DeviceID"]).Substring(0, ((String)WmiObject["DeviceID"]).IndexOf(@"\"));
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "InterfaceType", InterfaceType);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Drive",WmiObject["Drive"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Name",WmiObject["Name"]);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```